# QML Shape: How can I force data property to update in a clean way?

Tags: qt, qml, shapes, qqmlcomponent

I am trying to make a window where I can draw triangles and delete any of them with a **Shape{}**. In my example below, I can draw 2 types of triangle:

- Up triangle: green and filled
- Down triangle: yellow and not filled

Basically, I choose the type of triangle (with a button on the right-bottom corner) then I click anywhere on the window to get a triangle.

Once I click a triangle is created dynamically and it is stored in the property *triangleList*. Then I call the function *shape.update()* to update *data* property of shape. This part works well.

Here the function update I use in the Shape (since data is a list, I have to reassign to a new list.):

```
function update()
{
    data = [];
    var d = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < canvas.triangleList.length; i++)
    {
       d.push( canvas.triangleList[i] );
    }
    data = d;
}
```

My problem appears when I try to delete a triangle. In my example, I can delete the first, the last or all triangles. When I delete a triangle, first I delete the value in *triangleList* then I call again *shape.update()*. It works when I delete all triangles or the last one.

However, when I try to delete the first triangle, **data doesn't update its objects even if I give it a new list**. In fact, it always deletes the last triangle. Below an example:

[image]

data property understands there is one less triangle but it doesn't update the other triangles. The only solution I found is to change a property then come back to the original value. This way, it forces the data to update. 
But I have to do that for **every property** that can be different (colors and positions). Hence, my *update()* function looks like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.triangleList.length; i++)
                {
    d.push( canvas.triangleList[i] );

    ////// Change properties one by one to force the refresh

    // Force path redraw. Otherwise only the last path can be deleted
    d[i].startX++;d[i].startX--;

    // Force line color update
    d[i].strokeColor = "red"
    d[i].strokeColor = d[i].isUp ? "green" : "yellow";

    // Force fill color update
    d[i].fillColor = "red";
    d[i].fillColor = d[i].isUp ? "green" : "transparent";

    data = d;
}
```

I invite you to comment in/out these lines to see the difference.
I could use this trick to force the update but my real code is really bigger than this example and I use bindings.

So my question is: **Is there a way to force the update without having to change each property?**

Here the full code if you want to test it:

```
import QtQuick 2.9;
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2;
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0;

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true; width: 640; height: 480;

    Rectangle {
        id: canvas;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        color: "black";
        property var triangleList: [];
        property bool triangleUp: true;

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: {
                var triangle = componentTriangle.createObject(componentTriangle, {
                                                                "isUp" :  canvas.triangleUp,
                                                                "startX" :  mouse.x,
                                                                "startY" :  mouse.y,
                                                               }, canvas);

                canvas.triangleList.push(triangle);
                shape.update();
            }
        }   // MouseArea

        Shape {
            id: shape;

            anchors.fill: parent;

            function update()
            {
                data = [];
                var d = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < canvas.triangleList.length; i++)
                {
                    d.push( canvas.triangleList[i] );

                    ///////////// HOW TO AVOID THE PART BELOW? /////////////
                    ////// Change properties one by one to force the refresh

                    // Force path redraw. Otherwise only the last path can be deleted
                    d[i].startX++;d[i].startX--;

                    // Force line color update
                    d[i].strokeColor = "red"
                    d[i].strokeColor = d[i].isUp ? "green" : "yellow";

                    // Force fill color update
                    d[i].fillColor = "red";
                    d[i].fillColor = d[i].isUp ? "green" : "transparent";

                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }

                data = d;

                // I make sure data has at least one path to ensure the refresh
                if (data.length == 0)
                    data.push(Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.9; import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0; ShapePath {startX:0;startY:0;}', canvas,
                              "force_refresh"));
            }
        }  // Shape
    }   // Rectangle

    //////////// Buttons to handle the triangles

    Column {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
        anchors.right: parent.right;

        Button {

            text: canvas.triangleUp? "Draw triangleUp" : "Draw triangleDown";
            onClicked: { canvas.triangleUp = !canvas.triangleUp; }
        }   // Button

        Button {
            text: "Clear first";
            onClicked: {
                canvas.triangleList[0].destroy();
                canvas.triangleList.splice(0,1);
                shape.update();
            }
        }   // Button

        Button {
            text: "Clear last";
            onClicked: {
                canvas.triangleList[canvas.triangleList.length -1].destroy();
                canvas.triangleList.splice(canvas.triangleList.length -1,1);
                shape.update();
            }
        }   // Button

        Button {
            text: "Clear all";
            onClicked: {
                for (var i = 0; i < canvas.triangleList.length; i++)
                    canvas.triangleList[i].destroy();
                canvas.triangleList = [];
                shape.update();
            }
        }   // Button
    }

    //////////// Component to draw the triangle
    Component {
        id: componentTriangle;

        ShapePath {
            property bool isUp;
            property real offsetX: isUp? -20 : 20;
            property real offsetY: isUp? -30 : 30;

            strokeColor: isUp ? "green" : "yellow";
            strokeWidth: 3;
            fillColor: isUp ? "green" : "transparent";

            PathLine { x: startX - offsetX; y: startY - offsetY }
            PathLine { x: startX + offsetX; y: startY - offsetY }
            PathLine { x: startX; y: startY }
        }   // ShapePath
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help and feel free to ask me if I was not clear.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to handle many items (Shape) it is advisable to use a Repeater with a model. The repeater is responsible for displaying the items based on the information of the model, and to remove the items you just have to remove items from the model.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9;
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2;
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0;

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true; width: 640; height: 480;
    QtObject{
        id: internals
        property bool triangleUp: true;
    }
    ListModel{
        id: datamodel
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: canvas;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        color: "black";
        Repeater{
            model: datamodel
            Triangle{
                x: model.x
                y: model.y
                isUp: model.isUp
            }
        }
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: datamodel.append({"x": mouse.x, "y": mouse.y, "isUp": internals.triangleUp})
        }
    }
    Column {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
        anchors.right: parent.right;
        Button {
            text: internals.triangleUp ? "Draw triangleUp" : "Draw triangleDown";
            onClicked: internals.triangleUp = !internals.triangleUp;
        }   // Button

        Button {
            text: "Clear first";
            onClicked: if(datamodel.count > 0) datamodel.remove(0)
        }   // Button

        Button {
            text: "Clear last";
            onClicked: if(datamodel.count > 0) datamodel.remove(datamodel.count - 1)
        }   // Button

        Button {
            text: "Clear all";
            onClicked: datamodel.clear()
        }   // Button
    }
}
```

**Triangle.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9;
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.0

Shape {
    id: shape
    property bool isUp: false
    QtObject{
        id: internals
        property real offsetX: isUp? -20 : 20;
        property real offsetY: isUp? -30 : 30;
    }
    ShapePath {
        strokeWidth: 3;
        strokeColor: isUp ? "green" : "yellow";
        fillColor: isUp ? "green" : "transparent";
        PathLine { x: -internals.offsetX ; y: -internals.offsetY }
        PathLine { x: internals.offsetX; y: -internals.offsetY }
        PathLine { x: 0; y: 0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi eyllanesc. Thanks for your answer. Your approach is indeed good in my example. Unfortunately it works well if I use only Triangles (or one unique type).
In my work, I can draw a lot of shapes (lines, circle, rectangle, triangle) or I can just draw (no predefined shape). I'm not sure if the repeater will be good in this situation.


PS: I don't use ListModel because I have to bind some properties. I'm not 100% sure but I think ListModel doesn't support Qt.bindings

Comment: You are right. I shall be more specific.
You answer was perfect with my example so I'll marke it correct.
Thank you !